# Display result in Pacific Time zone displayed in UTC

Tags: postgresql, datetime, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

Hello i am quite new to ruby on rails so please be easy on me. I have a rails app which consist of a table displaying record. I have a search bar which filters the result of the table by date. My search bar select tag looks like this

```
select_tag :date, options_for_select(@previous_summary_history_dates.uniq), prompt: "Search by date", id: "summary-history-date-filter", class: "form-control"
```

This is my `@previous_summary_history_dates` in the controller from where the select tag gets the value from

```
@previous_summary_history_dates = SummarySheet.where(is_history: nil).pluck(:record_inserted_at).map{|a| a.strftime("%m/%d/%Y - %l:%M %p")}.uniq
```

I have set the `application.rb` file to this

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

I have a query for the search bar, which display the record in the table filtered by date selected from the select tag, which is something like this

```
@summary_history = SummarySheet.where(record_inserted_at: DateTime.strptime(params[:date], "%m/%d/%Y - %l:%M %p").at_beginning_of_minute..DateTime.strptime(params[:date], "%m/%d/%Y - %l:%M %p").at_end_of_minute)
```

This query works but it gives me the output in UTC format which doesnt match with my PCT format of the select tag and i get result as null. If i change my select tag time zone to UTC i get the desired output.

i tried `.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")` in my filter query  to convert the date in PCT but that didnt work

Can some one please suggest me how can i keep the select tage in PCT and fire the query and still get the dates filtered output? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the query to

```
@summary_history = SummarySheet.where(record_inserted_at: Time.zone.strptime(params[:date], "%m/%d/%Y - %l:%M %p").at_beginning_of_minute..Time.zone.strptime(params[:date], "%m/%d/%Y - %l:%M %p").at_end_of_minute)
```